# Rails 5: Why is javascript executing twice?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am in the process of learning Rails, and am struggling with best practices with respect to page-specific javascript.  Even with this simple approach, turbolinks (I believe) is causing javascript to execute twice if I visit a page and then return to it.

To simplify the scenario I created a new project with two controller actions, and started a server.

```
rails new jstest
cd jstest
rails g controller home index index2
rails server
```

Now I updated the views to the following:

index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Index2", home_index2_path %>
<script>
  console.log("hi from index!");
</script>
```

index2.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Index", home_index_path %>
<script>
  console.log("hi from index2!");
</script>
```

By navigating to /home/index, following the link to index2, then the link back to index I would expect to see:

```
hi from index!
hi from index2!
hi from index!
```

But instead, I get the third message twice:

```
hi from index!
hi from index2!
hi from index!
hi from index!
```

Why is it that my javascript executes twice on the second visit to index, and is there a better way to setup page specific javascript to avoid executing it twice?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was caused by turbolinks displaying a preview when revisiting the page.  My understanding is that turbolinks briefly displays a preview, to improve perceived load times, then replaces it.  In my example Javascript is executed both when the preview is displayed, and again when it is replaced.

In my scenario executing javascript twice was not causing any ill side effects, but if it were it could be stopped by disabling the preview with the following, per their [documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#opting-out-of-caching):

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-preview">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you, i spent so long figuring this out. I didn't know Turbolinks did this!